# Using a list from one function, inside another function python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. This might be a simple question, but if I have many functions that are dependent on each other how would I access lists from one function to use in another.

So...

```
def function_1():
    list_1=[]

def function_2():
    list_2= [2*x for x in list_1]

def function_3():
    list_3= [x * y for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

That is not the exact code but that is the idea of my problem. I would just put them all together in one function but I need them to be separate.

Comment: You can't, those lists are local variables inside the scope of those functions. You can make a module level list instead.

Comment: You _could_ declare them as ```global```s but I would discourage such things.  Its typically considered poor form and can get pretty confusing scopewise

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to use a class. A class is an object that has internal variables (in your case, the three lists), and methods (functions that can access the internal methods). So, this would be:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.list_1 = data if not data is None else []

    def function_2():
        self.list_2 = [2 * x for x in self.list_1]
```

And so on. For calling it:

```
foo = Foo()  # list_1 is empty
foo2 = Foo([1,2,3]) # list_1 is not empty
foo2.function_2()   
print foo2.list_2
# prints [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make them arguments and return values:

```
def function_1():
    return []

def function_2(list_1):
    return [2*x for x in list_1]

def function_3(list_1, list_2):
    return [x * y for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

(this suggests that `function_1` isn't much worth having...)

Answer (score 0):

The exact way will depend on exactly how you want things to work, but here is a simple example:

```
def function_1():
    return []

def function_2():
    return [2*x for x in function_1()]

def function_3():
    return [x * y for x, y in zip(function_1(), function_2())]
```

The key point is that functions do not generally just "do" things, they *return* things.  If you have a value in one function that you want to use in another function, the first function should return that value.  The second function should call the first function, and use its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are basically black boxes -- the outside world doesn't really know what goes on inside or what variables exist there. From the outside, other code only sees what goes in (the function's arguments) and what goes out (its return value).

So if your function computes some value that is to be used elsewhere, it should be `return`ed as the result of the function.

E.g.,

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

Takes a number, computes its square, and returns it.

Then you could do:

```
print(square(5))
```

and it will print 25.

So in your case you can return the lists and use them in the other functions, as the other answers showed:

```
def function_1():
    return []

def function_2():
    return [2*x for x in function_1()]

def function_3():
    return [x * y for x, y in zip(function_1(), function_2())]
```